# Redirect VI command output to a file

Tags: vim, vi

I want to export the output of `vi` command `:set fileencoding` to another file. It seems `vi`'s file encoding detection is better than `file` command.

How to do that?

I could write a macro with:

```
:set fileencoding
:q
```

but this won't export the output.

Comment: See also: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8378/dump-the-output-of-internal-vim-command-into-buffer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `vim`, you can use `redir` command. In command mode:

```
:redir > vim.output | set fileencoding | redir END
```

Then output of `set fileencoding` will be save to `vim.output`. There is many other options of `redir`, you can see `:help redir` for more details.

This works in `vim`, not in `vi`.